# Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException when trying to create a SWING/AWT frame from Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-boot, awt

In Spring Boot, when you try to create a Swing frame from the component that is the entry point of your app, you will get:

`Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException`

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, in your Application class in main, instead of:

`SpringApplication.run (Application.class, args)`

use

```
SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
builder.headless(false);
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = builder.run(args);
```